# How can I make sure that all the elements in an array are unique?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am building a Linq framework for school in Typescript as part of a homework project. I have a problem when it comes to the `Select` method. I pass the `Select` an array of properties, but the problem is that Typescript allows duplicate values in the array. Is there a way in Typescript or Javascript to have an array of only unique values?

Right now the `Select` method looks like this:

In the interface:

```
 Select: <K extends keyof T>(this: Table<T, U>, ...properties: K[]) => Table<Omit<T, K>, Pick<T, K> & U>
```

The implementation:

```
    Select: function <K extends keyof T>(this: Table<T, U>, ...properties: K[]): Table<Omit<T, K>, Pick<T, K> & U> {
        let selection = this.data.First.map(entry => pickMany(entry, properties))

        let result = this.data.map(
            first => first.map(entry => omitMany(entry, properties))
            ,
            second => merge_list_types(second.zip(selection))
        )

        return Table(result)
    }
```

Right now it is possible to say:

`customers.Select("name", "name", "age")`

As expected the code above will give me a type error, because `'name'` is already selected.

Comment: use a collection type that doesn't allow duplicates

Comment: Java and Javascript are two different things. Please correct your tag.

Comment: Did I say Java? Sorry I meant Javascript thanks for correcting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't ensure array uniqueness in a general way (at least not in a supported general way, you can do some crazy stuff with recursive type alias but they will likely break from a version to another).

We can create a conditional type that ensures uniqueness for up to a number of elements and add more as necessary.

```
type Omit<T, K extends PropertyKey> = Pick<T, Extract<keyof T, K>>
type IsUnique<T extends any[]> = UK0<T, "Items are not unique", {}>

type Tail<T extends any[]> = ((...a: T) => void) extends (p: any, ...t: infer P) => void ? P : [];
type UK0<T extends any[], TErr, TOk> = T extends [] ? TOk : T[0] extends Tail<T>[number] ? TErr : UK1<Tail<T>, TErr, TOk>
type UK1<T extends any[], TErr, TOk> = T extends [] ? TOk : T[0] extends Tail<T>[number] ? TErr : UK2<Tail<T>, TErr, TOk>
type UK2<T extends any[], TErr, TOk> = T extends [] ? TOk : T[0] extends Tail<T>[number] ? TErr : UK3<Tail<T>, TErr, TOk>
type UK3<T extends any[], TErr, TOk> = T extends [] ? TOk : T[0] extends Tail<T>[number] ? TErr : UK4<Tail<T>, TErr, TOk>
type UK4<T extends any[], TErr, TOk> = T extends [] ? TOk : T[0] extends Tail<T>[number] ? TErr : UK5<Tail<T>, TErr, TOk>
type UK5<T extends any[], TErr, TOk> = T extends [] ? TOk : T[0] extends Tail<T>[number] ? TErr : UK6<Tail<T>, TErr, TOk>
type UK6<T extends any[], TErr, TOk> = T extends [] ? TOk : T[0] extends Tail<T>[number] ? TErr : "Array to big"

class Table<T, U> {
    Select = function <K extends Array<keyof T>>(this: Table<T, U>, ...properties: K & IsUnique<K>): Table<Omit<T, K[number]>, Pick<T, K[number]> & U> {

        return null!;
    }
}

new Table<{ a: 0, b: 0}, {}>().Select("a") //ok
new Table<{ a: 0, b: 0}, {}>().Select("a", "a") // err
new Table<{ a: 0, b: 0}, {}>().Select("a", "b") //ok
```

A better way would actually to use an object type instead, objects intrinsically do not allow key duplication.

```
class Table<T, U> {
    Select = function <K extends Partial<Record<keyof T, true>>>(this: Table<T, U>, properties: K): Table<Omit<T, keyof K>, Pick<T, keyof K> & U> {

        return null!;
    }
}

new Table<{ a: 0, b: 0}, {}>().Select({ a: true }) //ok
new Table<{ a: 0, b: 0}, {}>().Select({ a: true, a: true }) // err
new Table<{ a: 0, b: 0}, {}>().Select({ a: true, b: true }) //ok
```

Comment: I was thinking about just passing an Object as parameter, but I think the teachers would prefer this syntax `Select("a", "b")` https://github.com/hogeschool/Software-Engineering-Minor

Comment: @IAMTHEBEST As a teacher myself I can tell you that is a good question to ask. Generally we don't mind people asking questions :-)

Comment: I like to comeback to you on this example, a teacher of mine came up with another solution in the halway. By making use of `Exclude`. I don't know how to implement this, but it has something to do with making an array type of the elements of type K and Excluding the allready selected values. Do you have any idea what he means or how to realize it.

Comment: @IAMTHEBEST There is no way to get around the recursive type alias issue. Recursive type aliases (except for very limited scenarios)  are not allowed. You can sort of kind of trick the compiler into letting you do it, but it is a) not recommended b) likely to break in future version as recursiveness checks  improve (and they do GH is full of recursive type aliases that worked but don't anymore). If your teacher has a better version I am curios to see it, but I doubt it works for an arbitrarily big array.

Comment: I will let you know